# How to convert sum of values in 5-min timesteps to raw data values

Tags: excel, database

In Excel, how do I convert 5-min Rain data --sum of values to raw data values? Sum of values reset every 24 hours.  Looking for Excel formula to quickly do this.

Screenshot below where the far right column (in red) is example of what i'm looking to get.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI59D.png)

Comment: Are you just looking for the difference between the current row and the previous row?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to include the 2nd part of my question.  I also need to convert the value to 1/100th (i.e. 2 = 0.02)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=(C2 - IF(A2 = A1, C1, 0)) / 100
```

Explanation:

- C2 is the current rain total, C1 is the previous row.
- If the current date is the same as the previous row's date, we take the difference in rain total.
- If the current date is different from the previous row's date (i.e. we have just passed from one date to the next), instead just subtract 0 because the count has just reset
- In either case, divide the resulting value by 100

Here's a demo in google sheets with a condensed data set (the corresponding functions work the same way in Excel):

[image: Demonstration in google sheets]